# Validating an array's length against another array's length using joi

Tags: javascript, arrays, joi

Is there a way to validate that two arrays need to have the same length using joi?

Here's an example:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  firstNames: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
  lastNames: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
});
```

If that was to work, it should also match both array's length so no `firstName` lacks a `lastName`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There certainly is, take a look at [`.assert()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectassertref-schema-message). You can use it to compare the values or attributes of two properties in your object.

For your example you can do this:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  firstNames: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
  lastNames: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
}).assert('firstNames.length', Joi.ref('lastNames.length'));
```

You can also optionally provide a more helpful error message as the third parameter of `.assert()`.

Comment: Some tests later, I see that `{ lastNames: 'Jones' }` is valid. Do you know any way to fix that false postive?

Comment: @Arkanoid this is because you're using the [`.single()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arraysingleenabled) modifier. It'll accept a single value from the array and convert it into an array once validated.

Comment: Oh no, that's actually fine. I understand we are checking that firstNames' length match lastNames' length but not the other way around, so being firstNames empty, that check doesn't run so it doesn't get checked. Maybe the option would be to mark both as required or to do the check the other way around too.