# Joi validate optional array from dynamically added fields

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have a form where the user can add more authors, the first one is required and is it has a its own fields validation

When the user add more authors these authors are stored in an array, so if the user does not add more authors it shows this error message:

```
"\"authors_first_name\" must be an array"
"\"authors_last_name\" must be an array"
"\"authors_country\" must be an array"
```

How to make the array optional when thare are not more than one author? 
But required when authors are added?

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    author_first_name: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'Author First Name is required'),
    author_last_name: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'Author Last Name is required'),
    author_country: Joi.string().valid(isoCodes).error(() => 'Author Country not valid'),

    authors_first_name: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).optional(),
    authors_last_name: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).optional(),
    authors_country: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(isoCodes).error(() => 'Country not valid')).optional()
});
```

I added the .optional() but the error keeps showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Oct/2022**

The old code will not work with the current Joi version as today is 17.7.0, this will work:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    first: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
    last: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
    country: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(...isoCodes)).single(),
}).assert('.first.length', Joi.ref('last.length'))
  .assert('.last.length', Joi.ref('country.length'));
```

[Here](https://runkit.com/embed/kdt74twabnkn) the test on runkit

**Old code**

Alright I got it working with this code:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    first: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
    last: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single(),
    country: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid(isoCodes)).single(),
}).assert('first.length', Joi.ref('last.length'))
  .assert('last.length', Joi.ref('country.length'));
```

Two additions to my original code:

1. [`.single()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arraysingleenabled) to the `array().items()`, this will accept string and arrays in the values
2. [`.assert()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectassertref-schema-message) to check if the array length are equals

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135823/453348), test code [here](https://runkit.com/embed/8g2c7ya3vjer)

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you are using here is misleading, you should have array of objects even if the user inserts only one author or multiple authors. Taking different arrays for first_name and last_name can result in problems like what if you got 5 first_names and 6 last_names. you can add validations but still this is a kind of buggy approach. You should use schema like this

```
    const schema = Joi.array().required().items(
    Joi.object().required().keys({
        author_first_name: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'Author First Name is required'),
        author_last_name: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'Author Last Name is required'),
        author_country: Joi.string().valid(isoCodes).error(() => 'Author Country not valid'),
    }))
```