# Set field max to equals another field (array) min value

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm currently using [joi](https://github.com/sideway/joi) to valite my data and I want to adchieve the next:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  arr: Joi.array().min(1).required(),
  qty: Joi.number().min(1).max(/* arr.min */)
});
```

Is there a way to do so? If so, how? I've been trying with:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  arr: Joi.array().min(1).required(),
  qty: Joi.number().min(1).max(Joi.ref('arr'))
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `Joi.ref('arr.length')` ? [Validating an array's length against another array's length using joi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127060/validating-an-arrays-length-against-another-arrays-length-using-joi)

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. The way you described it it looks like a common variable solution `minArrayValue = 5; joi.array().min(minArrayValue).required(); joi.number().min(minArrayValue)`....

Comment: Thanks @MaraBlack that was the solution!